# Convert Array<unsigned char>^ to an IBuffer

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Is there a way to Convert an `Array<unsigned char>^` to an `IBuffer^`? 
All i want to do is the equivalent of this in c# (WinRT) to c++/CX

```
Byte[] somebytes = GetBytes();
using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(somebytes.AsBuffer());
    ....
    DoSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

I could not find/use the "magic" extention method `.AsBuffer()` in c++/cx.

Is there an other way to achieve the .AsBuffer functionality in c++/cx?

Comment: This already googles well, [first hit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/816e5718-224d-4bb7-bf06-230e9c6cda5b/) looks good.